Deriving the Cable Equation from Maxwell's Equations
My goal is to reach equation 12 on this wikipedia page: Cable Theory. The demonstration is usually done by making an infinitesimal circuit, but I would like to get there via Maxwell's Equations by modelling a cylinder with anisotropic conductivity and radial polarization.

So, I started with an ansatz for the electric potential:
$$V(t,r,z) = R(r)U(t,z)$$
.
Notice that I dropped dependence on $\theta$ since the problem has rotational symmetry.
I also said that the polarization vector of the cable depends only on the radial component of the electric field:
$$\vec{P} = \epsilon_0 \chi E_r \hat{r}$$
The time variation of this vector gives rise to a bound current $\vec{J}_b = \partial_t \vec{P}$
.
The total current along the cable must be $\vec{J} = \vec{J}_f + \vec{J}_b$, which must also equal $\sigma \vec{E}$, with $\sigma$ being the conducivity tensor so that:
$$\sigma \vec{E} = \sigma_z E_z\hat{z} + \sigma_rE_r\hat{r}$$
Also, from the fourth Maxwell equation for materials:
$$\nabla \times H = \vec{J}_f + \partial_t \vec{D}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla \times H\right) = \nabla \cdot \vec{J}_f + \partial_t \nabla \cdot \vec{D}$$
$$0 = \nabla\cdot\vec{J}_f + \partial_t(\epsilon_0\nabla \cdot \vec{E} + \nabla \cdot \vec{P})$$
.
Elimitating $\vec{J}_f$ from the last equation with $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$ and doing all the algebra we end up with
$${\left(σ_{r} U\left(z, t\right) + ϵ_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}U\left(z, t\right)\right)} {\rm D[R]}\left(r, R\left(r\right)\right) + σ_{z} \frac{\partial^{2}}{(\partial z)^{2}}U\left(z, t\right) + ϵ_{0} \frac{\partial^{3}}{(\partial z)^{2}\partial t}U\left(z, t\right) = 0$$
Where
$${\rm D[R]}(r, R(r)) := \frac{1}{rR(r)}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(rR'(r)\right)$$
.
If we divide the previous equation by ${\left(σ_{r} U\left(z, t\right) + ϵ_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}U\left(z, t\right)\right)}$, we can conclude that ${\rm D[R]}(r, R(r))$ is some constant $C$. So
$${\left(σ_{r} U\left(z, t\right) + ϵ_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}U\left(z, t\right)\right)} C + σ_{z} \frac{\partial^{2}}{(\partial z)^{2}}U\left(z, t\right) + ϵ_{0} \frac{\partial^{3}}{(\partial z)^{2}\partial t}U\left(z, t\right) = 0$$
This looks almost equal to what is on the Wikipedia article, except for the factor $\frac{\partial^{3}}{(\partial z)^{2}\partial t}U\left(z, t\right)$. I have no idea how to get rid of it. Is it really supposed to be there?

It might benefit to write the actual Maxwell equation you plugged the various terms into to start.

Sorry, I said Maxwell's equations, but I actually used just one, the fourth: $\nabla \times H = \vec{J}_f + \partial_t \vec{D}$

I think the term $\tfrac{\partial^3}{\partial z^2\partial t}$ appears because of the $J_b \propto \partial_t P \propto  \partial_t E$ setting. This is your dielectric loss term and is  partly represented in the "cable" model by the shunt resistance $r_m$. In a harmonic excitation it should show up as the imaginary part of the permittivity tensor and is directly proportional to the frequency.

I'm actually quite surprised that you are taking the polarisation to be purely in the radial direction. That seems to be rather rare; usually in an antenna-like rod-like system, the flow of charges is along the cable, not radially. I don't know what it is you are trying to get out of this, but I'd check this.

Hi @naturallyInconsistent, this model stems from electrical activity travelling through neural 'cables' like axons and dendrites. If you look at the model in the Wikipedia link, the capacitance is taken to be across the radial direction, which is why I made that choice.
