Help Calculating the Electric Potential Around a Circle
Consider a circle or radius $r$ and two points $P$ and $Q$ that are separated by an angular distance $\alpha$. Also, let an electric field $\vec{E}$ be constant in the $\theta$ direction: $\vec{E} = E_0 \vec{\theta}$.
Such a field can be generated from a magnetic flux $\Phi(t) = \alpha t$ crossing the circle, which would then make $E_0 = -\frac{\alpha r}{2}$
Now, if I try to calculate the potential between P to Q, I could use a line element $\rm{d}\vec{l}=r\rm{d}\theta \hat{\theta}$ and do
$$V_{P\to Q} = \int_{0}^{\alpha}(E_0r\hat{\theta})\cdot\rm{d}\theta\hat{\theta} = r E_0 \alpha$$
But if I choose going the other way around the circle, I would get
$$V_{P\to Q} = rE_02\pi -\int_{0}^{\alpha}(E_0r\hat{\theta})\cdot\rm{d}\theta\hat{\theta} = r E_0 (2\pi - \alpha)$$
But voltage is a conservative field and shouldn't depend on the path taken. What did I do wrong?

The field you defined is non-conservative. If the curl of the field in non-zero, it is not a conservative field, and therefore you would never be able to make an electrostatic field like that.
On the other hand, if this field is an induced electric field, then it will be non-conservative, and so there is no issue. This is how you have non-zero induced EMFs around closed loops of wire, for example.

This is just a simplification from exercise 7.53 of Griffths, fourth edition.

@ÍcaroLorran oh, it's not an electrostatic field, but rather an induced electric field?

Yes, I think you could create this field by increasing the current linearly in a solenoid for example.  But I think your argument about the curl of E is what I was glancing over.

By the way, you're a biophysicist, right? Would you also happen to know if this derivation of the cable equation is valid? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/818297/deriving-the-cable-equation-from-maxwells-equations
